# My Bootstrap Navbar toogler button is just showing not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

Here is my project structure and my navbar toogler button is appearing but not working while i'm clicking the toggler button. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order of the scripts is wrong, first you must go jquery, popper and finally bootstrap, since bootstrap requires them, put them like this

```html
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of scripts tag must be:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

bootstrap requieres jquery for some functions